# Do we have any references to Tamil kings in Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, rama, tamil

Do we have any references to Tamil kings in Ramayana? Though Lord Rama goes to Lanka through Rameswaram, we dont see any reference to tamil kings in Ramayana? why they didnt support him with their army?

Comment: Not sure about kings, but we have multiple references of Maharshi Agastya.

Comment: There was concept of Tamil at that point. It was called by different name - Dravid I think.

Answer (score 3):

There's references to several kingdoms including [the Cholas (चोल), and the Pāṇḍyas (पाण्ड्य)] , and other kingdoms of the South, in the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa.

> #### [Chapter 41](https://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/kish/sarga41/kishkindha_41_frame.htm) - Kiṣkindhā kāṇḍa, Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa
>
> तथा वन्गान् कलिन्गाम् च कौशिकान् च समंततः । अन्वीक्ष्य दण्डक अरण्यम् स
> पर्वत नदी गुहम् ॥ ४-४१-११ ॥ नदीम् गोदावरीम् चैव सर्वम् एव अनुपश्यत ।
> तथैव **आन्ध्रान् च पुण्ड्रान् च चोलान् पाण्ड्यान् केरलान् ॥** ४-४१-१२ ॥
>
> > "Like that Vanga, Kalinga territories shall be searched along with
> > Kaushika territories available on their fringes, then cast about the
> > Dandaka forest all over its mountains, rivers, and its caves, then
> > River Godavari that courses through Dandaka forest, and **then the
> > provinces of Andhra, Puṇḍra, [Chola, Pāṇḍya], Kerala are to be searched
> > thoroughly.** [4-41-11, 12]
>
> .....
>
> ततो हेममयम् दिव्यम् मुक्ता मणि विभूषितम् ॥ ४-४१-१८ ॥युक्तम् कवाटम्
> पाण्ड्यानाम् गता द्रक्ष्यथ वानराः ।
>
> > "From there, on going to the **Pāṇḍya Kingdome you shall see a fully
> > golden castle-door bracing the compound-wall of the fortress**, which is
> > decorated with pearls and jewels, and conduct your search even in that
> > kingdom. [4-41-18b, 19a]

**The Chola and the Pāṇḍyas
kingdom, especially, maybe exactly mapped to the present day state of Tamil Nadu.**

Beyond the Chola and the Pāṇḍya kingdoms, I don't think if we have any other specific references to a Proper Noun name of a King,
in the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa atleast.

---

In my knowledge, the only person from the present day South to be mentioned in the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, is Mahaṛṣi Agastya:-

> तस्य आसीनम् नगस्य अग्रे मलयस्य महोजसम् || ४-४१-१५ द्रक्ष्यथ आदित्य
> संकाशम् अगस्त्यम् ऋषि सत्तमम् |
>
> > "You shall see the eminent sage Agastya, whose resplendence is akin to
> > that of the Sun, and who will be sitting on the top of that highly
> > resplendent Mt. Malaya. [4-41-15b, 16a]